# Use log4net with Ninject logging extensions in WebForms application

Tags: asp.net, logging, ninject-extensions

After some struggling I managed to get a working ASP.NET webforms application that uses the Ninject logging extension and log4net as logging framework. (credits to [this blog](http://coalvilledave.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/using-log4net-with-ninject) for the basics).
But I have some questions on how to continue.

First, I needed to make the ILogger property public, because it remained null if it was private or protected.
So now I have this:

```
[Inject]
protected ILogger _logger { get; set; }
```

Instead of:

```
private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

I can live with it, but it seems strange.

Another thing is the ThreadContext that log4net uses to fill the current context. I can still use it like this

```
using (ThreadContext.Stacks["NDC"].Push(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name))
{
     _logger.Info("test");
}
```

But offcourse that takes away all the abstraction that I just added.. 
So I'm looking for some experiences / best practices that other people may have with this scenario.

Additional question: I've upgraded log4net to 1.2.11.0 which is the current version in NuGet, and now Ninject.Logging.log4net is broken because it expects version 1.2.10.0 ... is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

> Additional question: I've upgraded log4net to 1.2.11.0 which is the
>   current version in NuGet, and now Ninject.Logging.log4net is broken
>   because it expects version 1.2.10.0 ... is there a way to fix that?

Did you try to fix the allowed versions with [xx] in the Packages.config file ?

```
  <package id="log4net" version="1.2.10"  allowedVersions="[1.2.10]" /> />
```

It will prevent next updates to upgrade to 1.2.11 or more.

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this.. I keep ending up with version 1.2.11.

Comment: I edit my answer, it is the allowedVersion attribute that must be modified. You have to uninstall the 1.2.11 version at first. Then update your packages.config file, and run an install-package command.